# Nodemon won't register change in docker

Tags: typescript, docker, express

I want to create a hot reload on my express + typescript Docker application. I've installed these packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
},
    "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
}
```

And i run the application using `nodemon src/index.ts`.

I've setup volumes to update the code in the container. When I checked the modified file in the container, it was updated. It works perfectly fine on my local machine. But nodemon won't register the changes in the docker container.

docker-compose:

```
api:
    build:
        context: ./api
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        target: base
    volumes:
        - ./api:/app
        - /app/node_modules
    container_name: api
    ports:
        - 5000:5000
    command: npm run dev
```

tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strict": true,
    }
```

Comment: Do you actually need the container here?  Can you run `nodemon` on your host to get live reloading on the frontend in a purely local environment, even if the backend and other dependencies are running in containers?

Answer (score 2):

I've added --legacy-watch in the dev script: `"dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch src/index.ts"` and its now working well